# Is there a way send intent over one activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

[image]

I'm making an app that using Intent.

I have three Activities.

To explain my situation, I name it as activity 1, 2, 3.

I have to send one intent from 1 to 3.

But I have to keep the order 1, 2, 3.

I have tried that send intent from 1 to 3, But it doesn't work.

I know i can solve this by sending intent from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3.

But I want to know it is possible or not.

And If it is possible, what is the way?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: activity 1 send broadcast , activity 3 receive [broadcast](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts)

Answer (score 0):

you can use local broadcast receiver ,in first activity you can send broadast along with intent startactivity and in third activity you can receive broadcast.
This is the link below that you can refer.

https://www.dev2qa.com/android-local-broadcast-manager-example/